# How to explain this? Something wrong in the web page source

Tags: asp.net, html, browser, web

This is really hard to tell but I will give a try.

I am developing a website using ASP.NET on VS2010 IDE. After Running my web site on my local computer the page works properly.
Once, I wanted to see the resource code on the browser (Mozilla Firefox 20). Well Nothing was looking wrong. Let me share my web page's `<head>` part:

```
<link href="../../Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/superfish.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now hold tight!

When I click on a path (for example: `Scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js`), I will show you what happens then:

```
<link href="../../../Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/superfish.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Normally the browser opens the js file's content in the code view, but here it prepends a `../` to the `../../Styles/Site.css`. The more I click the more it adds.

Is there any logical explanation of this behaviour? I have tried it in Firefox and Chrome.

By the way I am using `UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.dll` add-on.

Comment: i think ResolveUrl will help you  <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/yourscript") %>'></script> (not tested)

Comment: I do not have a problem. I just want to know why?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the URL gets rewritten during the request. Perhaps `UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.dll` is to blame for this?

Comment: Well I agree with you. But still do not understand. Also there is no problem. Everything goes well.